# Can "due" meaning "owed" be used without "to" in AmE? e.g. "the recognition which was due her"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, american-english

Encountered the following in a text I'm proofreading.

> ...tries to salvage the dignity due the situation

My instinct is to correct this to

> ...tries to salvage the dignity due **to** the situation

but the writer is American while I am (mostly) British, and it is possible this may be correct in American English. Googling unfortunately brings up many examples of "due to" meaning "because", which is not what I'm after.

To take another example:

> finally got the recognition she was due

Rephrasing...

> finally got the recognition due to her / finally got the recognition due her

The second, "due her" sounds weird to me, but is, according to the Cambridge definition above, correct.

**EDIT in response to comments saying that "due to" only means "because": https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due
(scroll down to the adjective definition)**

> **owed as a debt or as a right:**
>
> The rent is due (= should be paid) at the end of the month.
> £50 is due **to** me (US due me) from the people I worked for last month.
> Our thanks are due **to** everyone.

Some more examples of "due to", to put those arguments to rest:

- *Arguably the handling of those bones as tools of research is also incompatible with the respect due to humanity* [British Diplomacy in Northern India](https://books.google.es/books?id=bmBoAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA668&dq=%22respect+due+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj505fMk8T4AhWLxYUKHe9FBaIQ6AF6BAgHEAI)
- *In the morning we had talked of old families, and the respect due to them.* [The Life of Samuel Johnson vol.II](https://books.google.es/books?id=x1myDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&dq=%22respect%20due%20to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYyLexk8T4AhXVgHMKHXnhCKI4HhDoAXoECAgQAg)
- *It stood on its neck/with a smile well-bred/And bowed three times to me!/It was none of your impudent/off-hand nods/But as humble as could be/For it clearly knew/The deference due/To a man of pedigree* [The Mikado](https://books.google.es/books?id=Gh4_AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA278&dq=%22deference+due%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMytGgl8T4AhVJiRoKHWIVCp0Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22deference%20due%22&f=false)
- *My thanks are due to former colleagues...*
- *'And you have accepted what was not due to you.' D'Artagnan's eyes flashed. * [The Vicomte de Bragelonne](https://books.google.es/books?id=lYhhug2M5DkC&pg=PA451&dq=%22due+to+you%22+-hearings+-volume+-report+-federal+-committee+-hearing+-law&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8z8KilsT4AhWtxoUKHVhTCZ44ChDoAXoECAYQAg)
- *The first line gives the 'agreed fee', which is the total amount due to you, not including any VAT.* [How to Be an Illustrator](https://books.google.es/books?id=d_UgEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT197&dq=%22due%20to%20you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUwNHflcT4AhVFiRoKHTTaBKEQ6AF6BAgLEAI)

What I want to know is - in such cases, in American English, may we use "due" without the "to"?

Comment: I don't think changing "due" to "due to" preserves the meaning  you want. Generally,  "due to" means "because of" or "resulting from".

Comment: the original phrasing refers to *the dignity **which** the situation **merits / justifies / deserves***. Your rewrite seems to refer to *an attempt to salvage [some] dignity **because of** the situation*, but it doesn't really make sense to me. Note that the preposition ***to*** in *She finally got the recognition due to her* is "stylistically optional" - it's syntactically fine with or without, and the meaning is unchanged.

Comment: Yes, "due" stands for *that is due in* or *owed in*. @FumbleFingers has good choices, too. Any mail due today is **expected in** today's mail. The dignity we'd expect in this situation is what we're trying to salvage. Still, if nothing's wrong with a sentence other than the head I'm scratching, yes, I reword.

Comment: "due" in this case means "owed", and just as we say "the money owed to me" we can say "the respect due to me". See my edits and link to the Cambridge English dictionary.

Comment: Due to circumstances beyond our control, "due to" should only be used in cases where blame is being assigned.

Comment: @Notiophilus for something like "the respect due to me", if I had to use "due", I'd write "the respect that I am due".

Comment: Leave nothing to chance. Or Murphy will have his due.

Comment: @muru "my due respect" sounds slightly more natural to me (AmE), but agreed that "the respect due to me" could sound like I am the cause of the respect.

Comment: This is starting to sound like a soft drink commercial.

Comment: "finally got the recognition she was due" - what's wrong with that? Also, your title simply has a word out of order : "the recognition which was [her] due[.]" - However "... tries to salvage the dignity due the situation" - the question should be can you say (*the*) *dignity* w/o *of* after it and then a noun. What's the entire sentence?

Comment: As a speaker of American English, I always try to [give the devil his due](https://www.theidioms.com/give-the-devil-his-due/), but I don't give the devil what is due to him.

Comment: "My instinct is to correct this to" your instinct is incorrect, as most have pointed out.

Comment: (The six bullet point examples are precisely examples of the other, different, usage.)

Answer (score 32):

As a native speaker of AmE, I find that *the recognition due her* sounds fairly standard to me (leaving aside the spoken similarity with *do her*).

The alternative *...due to her* does seem clearer, and it's one of those situations where the longer I think about it, the more I prefer the clearer alternative. But when I plug the longer form back into the original sentence:

> *...tries to salvage the dignity due to the situation.*

now I hate it. Your interpretation (the dignity is owed to the situation) is probably grammatically sound, but the whole phrase has become ambiguous. It just sounds too close to the alternative meaning, "because of the situation." Even if that usage is largely deprecated in academic writing, it's such common usage in the US that my brain can't help but parse the sentence that way.

In your shoes but as an AmE proofreader I'd write something like the following: "Probably standard in AmE; understandable that you want to avoid "due *to* the situation"; even so, consider clearer alternatives, e.g. 'tries to salvage the dignity merited by the situation.'"

Comment: Or even, "tries to salvage the dignity [that] the situation merited."

Answer (score 12):

I am also British, but to me the original phrase sounds correct and has a different meaning to what you are trying to correct it to.

"*...tries to salvage the dignity due the situation*" implies that the situation owed/dued/deserving of dignity.

However, the phrase  "*...tries to salvage the dignity due **to** the situation*" is ambiguous because it could imply the above, or it could imply that the situation was somehow causing dignity in some context.

This can be seen more in the second context if we add another character.

"*Peter finally got the recognition due to her*" implies *she* has been working to make sure that Peter got the recognition her deserved.

Whereas "*Peter finally got the recognition due her*" doesn't really make sense. Or implies that Peter is in fact female.

Basically, I think both are fine, but I prefer the original phrase because it is less ambiguous.

Comment: I would interpret "Peter finally got the recognition due her" as being that Alice (or whoever her referred to) was due the recognition, but Peter got it.  "Peter finally got the recognition due to her" could also mean that Peter got the recognition that Alice should have got, or it could mean "because of" her as you suggest (and OP mentioned)

Comment: One can rescue "Peter finally got the recognition due her" by italicizing "her," if there's helpful context.

Comment: @Dragonel - that's both very clever and correct.

Answer (score 0):

> In American English, may we use "due" without the "to"?

Yes (I speak US English), but not in the sentence you're proofreading:

> ...tries to salvage the dignity due the situation

because that would mean that the *situation* was owed a certain amount of dignity, which would be pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that 'due' here follows a definition that is synonymous with 'owed'.

> ...tries to salvage the dignity owed (to) the situation...

Which is why the lack of 'to' seems a bit jarring to your ear.

However, another definition of 'due' is synonymous with 'fitting' or 'proper' or 'appropriate'.

> ...tries to salvage the dignity fitting the situation...

Which sounds perfectly reasonable to me.  Perhaps this was the meaning your writer intends?